# Duplicate key error even on update in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to update or insert a document in MongoDb:

```
return Collection.UpdateOneAsync(x => x.UserId == document.UserId,
     document.GetUpdateDefinition(),
     new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
```

And I include `UserId` too in update definition for when it is an `insert` and the document didn't exist:

```
public UpdateDefinition<UserModel> GetUpdateDefinition()
{
    return Builders<UserModel>.Update
        .Set(nameof(UserId), UserId)
        .Set(nameof(FirstName), FirstName)
        .Set(nameof(LastName), LastName)
}
```

But sometimes I get this error:

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: Data index: _id_ dup key: { : "3232333" }
```

How to fix this error? Thanks.

**Update**
and here is my model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error is on the `_id` and not the `UserId`. Have you defined an [Id Generator](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators)? Because it looks like you have and it's not doing the correct job.

Comment: Hi @NeilLunn I don't work with `_id` , I've defined my own ID.. please look at my updated post

Comment: `_id_ dup key` that's the name of the index. `_id_` . So this is the primary key. Typically it's an `ObjectId` value, but your value is a "string" so you actually do have something assigning that string. This is done with a "IdGenerator" so the driver picks up a `$setOnInsert` for "upserts". You do have something in your code assigning it. Best to find out where that is.

Comment: @NeilLunn Is it possible this happen on concurrent upserts? when it checks the document doesn't exist so tries to `insert`, but meanwhile another process has inserted the same id.

Comment: Nothing to do with concurrency. You have some code which is creating the value for the `_id` primary key, just as I have told you twice. There is no other way for an "upsert" to receive the value which is shown in the error. Read The links and check your code. Do a global search for `IdGenerator`. The code assigning this value is at fault.

Comment: I really don't have anymore code other than what I've shown here. I've set `UserId` to be the id using `[BsonId]` attribute. It will be converted to `_id` behind the scene in the official mongodb driver. The weird thing is, even if it's a duplicate which sometimes is, it should become an `update` instead of `insert`, that's why I'm using `upsert`. I don't see it meaningful to show duplicate error in an `upsert`